# Dart how to parse invalid JSON format?

Tags: json, flutter, dart

I am working with OpenAI API for chatGPT. The response is ByteStream. When I use `utf8.decode` to convert bytes to String the result is

```
 data: {"id":"chatcmpl-6rcqJGoHnJLz94ZNxcA569JsJSJsR","object":"chat.completion.chunk","created":1678238715,"model":"gpt-3.5-turbo-0301","choices":[{"delta":{"role":"assistant"},"index":0,"finish_reason":null}]}
```

which I can't use inside `jsonDecode()`.

Decoded String is in this form.

```json
data: {"id":"chatcmpl-6rcqJGoHnJLz94ZNxcA569JsJSJsR","object":"chat.completion.chunk","created":1678238715,"model":"gpt-3.5-turbo-0301","choices":[{"delta":{"role":"assistant"},"index":0,"finish_reason":null}]}
data: {"id":"chatcmpl-6rcqJGoHnJLz94ZNxcA569JsJSJsR","object":"chat.completion.chunk","created":1678238715,"model":"gpt-3.5-turbo-0301","choices":[{"delta":{"role":"assistant"},"index":0,"finish_reason":null}]}
```

Comment: Do you mean that you have a `String` of the form: `'data: {"id":"chatcmpl..."}'`?  If so, then just strip off the `'data: '` prefix first.  For example, `jsonDecode(s.substring('data: '.length))`

Answer (score 1):

As @gamesdlin mentioned in his comment.

You can just strip `data:`  part from the resultant string

```
 data: {"id":"chatcmpl-6rcqJGoHnJLz94ZNxcA569JsJSJsR","object":"chat.completion.chunk","created":1678238715,"model":"gpt-3.5-turbo-0301","choices":[{"delta":{"role":"assistant"},"index":0,"finish_reason":null}]}
```

And use jsonDecode like:

```
result = "data: {"id":"chatcmpl-6rcqJGoHnJLz94ZNxcA569JsJSJsR","object":"chat.completion.chunk","created":1678238715,"model":"gpt-3.5-turbo-0301","choices":[{"delta":{"role":"assistant"},"index":0,"finish_reason":null}]}"

jsonDecode(result.substring(result.indexOf("{"));)
```

Update:

Use the following `regex`

```
RegExp exp = RegExp(r'data:\s*{([^}]+)}');
Match match = exp.firstMatch(response)!;
String result = match.group(1)!;

jsonDecode(result);
```

Comment: This was my initial solution but sometimes decoded string is `data: {...} data: {...}` so it only removes first `data: `

Comment: give me all instances of your decoded string looks like , is this the only other form your decoded string looks like ? For me to provide genearlized solution i need to know the pattern

Comment: @Soliev Split it into lines and then remove the `data: ` prefix from each line.